# How to do basic calculations in Nuxt data()

Tags: math, nuxt.js

I have an array of objects within my `data()` in my Nuxt app set up like this.

```
myObjects: [
    {
        firstNumber: 2,
        secondNumber: 3,
        thirdNumber: this.firstNumber * this.secondNumber
    }
]
```

As you can see from above I am trying to multiply `firstNumber` by `secondNumber` to get `thirdNumber` which I will show on the screen to the user of the app.

Unfortunately `thirdNumber` shows as NaN on the front end. I would have expected `thirdNumber` to show on the front end as 6.

I have tried to force type by changing `thirdNumber` to `thirdNumber: Number(this.firstNumber) * Number(this.secondNumber)` but the result is the same. I've tried a few other similar variants of that but the result is always the same... NaN.

This seems like it should be fairly simple so I cannot work out what I am doing wrong.

EDIT:

To help further, here is a slightly expanded version of the code.

```
<!-- HTML -->

<div v-for="(item, index) in myObjects">
    <p v-text="item.firstNumber"></p>
    <p v-text="item.secondNumber"></p>
    <p v-text="item.thirdNumber"></p>
</div>

<!-- DATA -->

data() {
    return {
        myObjects: [
            {
                firstNumber: 2,
                secondNumber: 3,
                thirdNumber: this.firstNumber * this.secondNumber
            },
            {
                firstNumber: 2,
                secondNumber: 3,
                thirdNumber: this.firstNumber * this.secondNumber
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to do these using a computed properts, like

```
computedObjects() {
      return this.myObjects.map((item) => {
        return {
          ...item,
          thirdNumber: item.firstNumber * item.secondNumber,
        };
      });
    },
```

using on the template like this:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="(item, index) in computedObjects" :key="index">
    <p v-text="item.firstNumber"></p>
    <p v-text="item.secondNumber"></p>
    <p v-text="item.thirdNumber"></p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: this brings me an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'myObjects')`. As a further point, I display multiple `thirdNumber`s across the page (i.e. the thirdNumber for each object) and the code above looks like it would just deal with the first item in the array. Thanks for posting. Can you see what needs tweaking to get rid of the error and deal with the fact I want to access each object in the array, not just the first?

Comment: I've edited the question to add a bit more context